# Problem with TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@null">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:src="@drawable/photo_profile" android:id="@+id/profil_image"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginRight="10dip" />
        <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="15dip">
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/experience"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:textSize="16sp" />
                <TextView android:id="@+id/profil_experience"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:textSize="16sp" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/secteur"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:textSize="16sp" />
                <TextView android:id="@+id/profil_secteur"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:textSize="16sp" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/lieu"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:textSize="16sp" />
                <TextView android:id="@+id/profil_lieu"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:textSize="16sp" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/niveau_etude"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:textSize="16sp" />
                <TextView android:id="@+id/profil_niveau"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:textSize="16sp" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/entreprise"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:textSize="16sp" />
                <TextView android:id="@+id/profil_societe"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:textSize="16sp" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/profil_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and i got this :

http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/819091Capture.png

I have two problems :
 * I can't see the Checkbox
 * The text is cutted

and thank you for your attention

Comment: give fixed size to your text view rather than wrap content it will not span as per the content and might help u

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any text in your checkbox. Try adding a text="Some Text" to see if it shows up. I'm guessing since you have it set to wrap_content, you don't actually have any content to wrap.

Comment: thank you for your reply ,i add a text dynamically , the problem when i have a long text , i get it cutted

Comment: you can see the image , it can help you to understand my problem

Comment: In the image I see no checkbox whatsoever. Just your textviews.

Comment: yes , and thisis my problem , the table layout take all the place :s

Comment: Have you tried setting the layout_weight? I have not messed with it much, I think think it may assist you. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your TableLayout in a ScrollView of fixed height.so bottom area can be used for CheckBox.